# Why does inner join result in more rows than the dataframe with lesser rows?

Tags: pandas, merge

I would like to ask why does inner join result in more rows than df_1? I thought that inner_join only retains those rows with customer_id value present in both df_1 and df_6, so the maximum number of rows should be 99441. I do not understand why I get 99455 rows instead? Thank you.

Please check out my screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AY8D.png

Answer (score 0):

The total number of rows is less than or equal both dataframes, which is expected. I think you are confusing 99455 with 96455. Your output was 96455.